# angularjs validate email id press enter button

Tags: angularjs

I have form with angular bootstrap modal, in that modal has a text box and add email button then default button mode is in disable mode until you type correct email id, when you type correct email id then button mode will change to enable mode then you can click that button, when click on button it calls the method called addOrRemove(), as well as when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> button it calls the same method but i want that when i press <kbd>Enter</kbd> button it needs to check the text box is it correct email id  or not, if it is correct then it proceed otherwise it will show a error message.

[My code here in plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/L1SD59951vKya7IBq7RV?p=preview)

My html code is

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
<head>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js"></script>
<script src="example.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div >
   <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent">
      <div class="modal-header">
          <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <li ng-repeat="item in items " ng-form="subForm">
              <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="item.email" required ng-pattern="/^[_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/"  ng-enter="addOrRemove($index,item.email)"/>
              <span ng-show="subForm.name.$error.required" style="color: red">Email required</span>
              <span ng-show="subForm.name.$invalid" ng-hide="subForm.name.$error.required" style="color: red">Invalid email</span>
              <button ng-disabled="subForm.name.$invalid || subFform.name.$dirty" ng-click="addOrRemove($index,item.email)" >{{item.value}}</button>
               expression: {{subForm.name.$invalid}}
          </li>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
          <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
      </div>
  </script>

  <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('lg')" >Large modal</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my javaScript code

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
//var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log) {
app.controller('ModalDemoCtrl',['$scope', '$modal','$log','$rootScope',
function controller($scope, $modal, $log, $rootScope)
{
$scope.open = function (size) {
$scope.val = "";
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
  templateUrl: 'myModalContent',
  controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
  size: size,
  backdrop: 'static',
  resolve: {
    items: function () {
      return $scope.items;
    }
  }
});

modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
  $scope.selected = selectedItem;
}, function () {
  $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
});
};}]);

// Please note that $modalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $modal service used above.

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope,$rootScope, $modalInstance) {
$scope.check2 = "hllo";

$scope.items = [
    {
        value: "Add email",
        state: "1",
        email: ""
    }];
$scope.check1;


$scope.addOrRemove = function(indexSelected,rcvEmail)
{//alert($rootScope.email1);
    console.log("just check email",rcvEmail);
    console.log("length of the object",$scope.items.length);
    event.preventDefault();
    if($scope.items[indexSelected].state == 1)
    {
        //console.log($scope.items[indexSelected].state);
        $scope.items[indexSelected].value = "Remove email";
        $scope.items[indexSelected].state = "0";
        $scope.items[indexSelected].email = rcvEmail;
        $scope.items.push({value: "Add email", state: "1"});
    }
    else
    {
        //console.log($scope.items[indexSelected].state);
        //$scope.items.push({value: "Remove email", state: "1"});
        $scope.items.splice(indexSelected, 1);
    }

};

$scope.ok = function () {
$modalInstance.close();
};

$scope.cancel = function () {
$modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};

};


app.directive('ngEnter', function () {
console.log("directive checke");
return function (scope, element, attrs) {
    element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
        if(event.which === 13) {
            scope.$apply(function (){
                scope.$eval(attrs.ngEnter);
            });

            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
};
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please see here : http://plnkr.co/edit/DP2FvwePCp7rjIe2yN2n?p=preview

**Modal :**

add ng-keypress to your form `ng-keypress="keyPressed($event, item, $index)"`

```
<div class="modal-body">
          <li ng-repeat="item in items " ng-form="subForm" ng-keypress="keyPressed($event, item, $index)">
              <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="item.email" required ng-pattern="/^[_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/"  ng-enter="addOrRemove($index,item.email)"/>
              <span ng-show="subForm.name.$error.required" style="color: red">Email required</span>
              <span ng-show="subForm.name.$invalid" ng-hide="subForm.name.$error.required" style="color: red">Invalid email</span>
              <button ng-disabled="subForm.name.$invalid || subFform.name.$dirty" ng-click="addOrRemove($index,item.email)" >{{item.value}}</button>
               expression: {{subForm.name.$invalid}}
          </li>

      </div>
```

**JS for Modal**
add  $scope.keyPressed to your ModalInstanceCtrl

```
var ModalInstanceCtrl = function($scope, $rootScope, $modalInstance) {
  $scope.check2 = "hllo";

  $scope.items = [{
    value: "Add email",
    state: "1",
    email: ""
  }];
  $scope.check1;
  $scope.keyPressed = function(eve, email, idx) {
    if (eve.charCode === 13) {

      addOrRemove(email, idx);
    }
  }

  $scope.addOrRemove = function(indexSelected, rcvEmail) { //alert($rootScope.email1);
    console.log("just check email", rcvEmail);
    console.log("length of the object", $scope.items.length);
    // event.preventDefault();
    if ($scope.items[indexSelected].state == 1) {
      //console.log($scope.items[indexSelected].state);
      $scope.items[indexSelected].value = "Remove email";
      $scope.items[indexSelected].state = "0";
      $scope.items[indexSelected].email = rcvEmail;
      $scope.items.push({
        value: "Add email",
        state: "1"
      });
    } else {
      //console.log($scope.items[indexSelected].state);
      //$scope.items.push({value: "Remove email", state: "1"});
      $scope.items.splice(indexSelected, 1);
    }

  };

  $scope.ok = function() {
    $modalInstance.close();
  };

  $scope.cancel = function() {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };

};
```

Comment: When i press enter button it validates the email in text box if it correct then it calls the method otherwise it shows the error message.

Comment: @BharathKumar please see line 46 press enter doing exactly this same as pressing add email button

Comment: Ok i saw but it will not validate the email in textbox... When i press enter it should validate the email id in text box but it is not validating the email and call to the method...

Comment: Thank you it is working, small doubt can i move the cursor automatically into new text box when it generates..

Comment: @BharathKumar get focus is a bit tricky but I'm sure you can find solution here as that question occurred few times already